# Composer autoload doesn't work for tests in Travis CI

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, travis-ci

I know, isnt as if Composer or Travis not work, I do not get to do that work fine, I do not understand how autoload runs locally but not in Travis build. 
If someone could shed light on this problem that I have, I would be very grateful.

The problem specifically is displayed when you can not find an interface ... 
as the error pops up when you do not see the "namespace\namespace\interface", I think that should be the autoload, should not be loading very well for the test in Travis.

Here is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Interface 'RestGalleries\Interfaces\User' not found in /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/src/RestGalleries/APIs/Flickr/FlickrUser.php on line 15
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/phpunit:0
PHP   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/bin/phpunit:46
PHP   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
PHP   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /home/travis/.phpenv/versions/5.4.25/share/pyrus/.pear/php/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
PHP   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
PHP   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
PHP   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
PHP   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
PHP  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:783
PHP  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
PHP  12. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:838
PHP  13. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  14. RestGalleriesTest->testFindUserReturnApiUserObject() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
PHP  15. Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:0
PHP  16. Composer\Autoload\includeFile() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:269
PHP  17. include() /home/travis/build/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php:363
```

Frankly I can not think it can be right now. I leave my code on github and the failing build (Until the time, i have failed at all with this, but leave the last build to see).

Github: https://github.com/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries

Travis CI build: https://travis-ci.org/estebanmatias92/RestGalleries/jobs/19337261

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you are working on OSX which has case-insensitive filesystem by default? Try renaming the folder `interfaces` to `Interfaces`.

Comment: Following your advice, i've tried backwards, I changed Interfaces for interfaces and it worked (of course, also i changed the namespaces). Thank you very much.